# mapRectThatFits : What does it do?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

I don't understand mapRectThatFits in the slightest. Here is a simple line of code:

```
MKMapRect zoomRectNorm = [mapView mapRectThatFits:zoomRect];
// BREAKPOINT HERE
```

Now lets look at the debugger.

Print zoomRect:

```
(lldb) p zoomRect
(MKMapRect) $1 = {
  (MKMapPoint) origin = {
    (double) x = 4.2997e+07
    (double) y = 9.36865e+07
  }
  (MKMapSize) size = {
    (double) width = 26493.1
    (double) height = 148685
  }
}
```

Print zoomRectNorm:

```
(lldb) p zoomRectNorm
(MKMapRect) $2 = {
  (MKMapPoint) origin = {
    (double) x = 4.29283e+07
    (double) y = 9.36379e+07
  }
  (MKMapSize) size = {
    (double) width = 163840
    (double) height = 245760
  }
}
```

So it adjusted the aspect ratio to 2:3 but it did not maintain the width, the height, or the origin!?

According to the documentation it should return:

> A map rectangle that is still centered on the same point of the map
>   but whose width and height are adjusted to fit in the map view’s
>   frame.

Whats the deal? I would expect it to maintain the origin (as stated in the docs) and at least one of the width/height?

Answer (score 0):

MapRect that fits will zoom out until it hits a zoom level that can contain your region do that the tiles are displayed in their native resolution.

Comment: What about the origin? Why does it change that?

Comment: Where is your region based, could it be so close to the dateline (which mkmapview can't cross) that the centre is pushed aside as it zooms back

Answer (score 0):

It gives you back the map rect that you would get if you used `setVisibleMapRect` on the mapview. The center should be the same. The origin probably won't. You'll have to think about the difference between origin and center to understand why. The other thing to understand is that, although you ask for a specific map rect to be set, the mapview will always set its own idea of what is best. Its idea of what is best is the one that allows it to display tiles without zooming in or out.